# Append element to publisher only if it wants to finish without publishing any value

Tags: swift, combine

I have two publishers, both of which can publish a value or complete without publishing any at all. I'm combining the two publishers and comparing their values and doing some post-processing on the values and saving them to my local CoreData. Simplified code looks like:

```
let p1 = ["1"]
    .publisher
    .map { Int($0) }

let p2 = ["2"]
    .publisher
    .map { Int($0) }

let p1p2 = p1.combineLatest(p2)
    .map { $0 == $1 }
    .sink { print($0) }
```

But in case one of the publishers doesn't publish any value, I still need to save the remaining value to my local DB. The issue is that the combineLatest operator doesn't fire any event if one of the publisher finishes without ever firing a value. I tried prepend and append operators, but they cannot be combined with any conditions, say if one of the publishers finish without publishing any value.

For example, something like:

```
let p1String: [String] = []
let p1 = p1String.publisher
    .map { Int($0) }
    .if(completionWithoutPublishing, perform: { prepend(nil) })
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: If it has already completed, you can't prepend to it, can you?

Comment: That's the reason for my question. I don't know if it can be done, but if by some operator magic, I can prepend only when it sees a completion without ever seeing a value, my problems would be solved easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `replaceEmpty` operator:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/zip4/replaceempty(with:)

https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsreplaceempty.html

It does just what you describe: it emits its special value only if the upstream finishes without having published.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your custom operator that does this. You only need to implement `receive(subscriber:)`. You do that by adding your custom logic to the upstream publisher (in your case, the `map`), then attach the subscriber parameter to it.

```
struct IfEmpty<Upstream: Publisher>: Publisher {
    let upstream: Upstream
    let output: Output
    let handler: (() -> Void)?
    
    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input {
        var hasOutput = false
        upstream.handleEvents(receiveOutput: { (_) in
            hasOutput = true
        }, receiveCompletion: { (_) in
            if !hasOutput {
                subscriber.receive(output)
                handler?()
            }
        }).receive(subscriber: subscriber)

    }
    
    typealias Output = Upstream.Output
    
    typealias Failure = Upstream.Failure
}

extension Publisher {
    func ifEmpty(publish output: Output, andDo handler: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> IfEmpty<Self> {
        IfEmpty(upstream: self, output: output, handler: handler)
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
let p1String: [String] = []
let p1 = p1String.publisher
    .map { Int($0) }
    .ifEmpty(publish: nil)
    .print()
    .sink(receiveValue: { _ in })
/*
receive subscription: (HandleEvents)
request unlimited
receive value: (nil)
receive finished
*/
```

```
let p1String: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
let p1 = p1String.publisher
    .map { Int($0) }
    .ifEmpty(publish: nil)
    .print()
    .sink(receiveValue: { _ in })
receive subscription: (HandleEvents)
request unlimited
receive value: (Optional(1))
receive value: (Optional(2))
receive value: (Optional(3))
receive finished
*/
```

Comment: @Sweeper But you get full marks for ingenuity!

Comment: Awesome. This is great. But, I'll go with replaceEmpty :)

Comment: @Aswath That's alright :) I've added an optional `handler` parameter, just to be a little different from `replaceEmpty`, inspired by the closure syntax in your attempt.